# Bluetooth RSA encryption at application level

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rsa, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

We need to add RSA encryption after my Qualcomm (QCA4020) Iot device gets paired to android app.
Not sure how to implement this case to exchange RSA public keys between devices.

1. After device pairing, do we need to define GATT service to exchange RSA public keys?
2. if yes are there any standard GATT service defined by bluetooth for key exchange?
3. What is the standard way for implementing application level encryption that is defined by bluetooth?

Looking for some brief explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> After device pairing, do we need to define GATT service to exchange RSA public keys?

Yes, if you want to use you own security procedure at application level you need to define a GATT service to transfer the keys. You could reuse an existing one as long as you can differentiate between a normal message and your keys

> if yes are there any standard GATT service defined by bluetooth for key exchange?

No, there are, to my knowledge, no predefined GATT services available for key exchanges

> What is the standard way for implementing application level encryption that is defined by bluetooth?

There is no standard, application level security is totally up to you. I personally would go with a more lightweight encryption method like AES with an ECDH key exchange